# C# Timer thread crash, BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, wpf, window, opacity

I've an "animateMyWindow" class to change opened window's opacity with Timer.

```
    namespace POCentury
{
    class animateMyWindow
    {
        Timer _timer1 = new Timer();
        Window _openedWindow = null;
        public void animationTimerStart(object openedWindow)
        {
            if (openedWindow == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Hata");
            }
            else
            {
                _openedWindow = (Window)openedWindow;
                _timer1.Interval = 1 * 25;
                _timer1.Elapsed +=  new ElapsedEventHandler(animationStart);
                _timer1.AutoReset = true;
                _timer1.Enabled = true;
                _timer1.Start();
            }
        }
        private void animationStart(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_openedWindow.Opacity == 1)
                animationStop();
            else
                _openedWindow.Opacity += .1;
        }
        private void animationStop()
        {
            _timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

animationStart function can't reach my window because it is working on a different thread.
I've tried Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and can't make it work.
Can you help me with doing that?

Comment: If this is WPF you should check the http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23257/Beginner-s-WPF-Animation-Tutorial There are some nice animation tools within WPF

Comment: You would avoid the need for using the Dispatcher if you would use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx). Even easier would be to entirely drop the timer stuff and animate the opacity by a [DoubleAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.aspx).

Comment: Thank you @Clemens, It is working now with DispatcherTimer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can't access the `openedWindow` inside the `animationStart` event because it's happening in a different thread. You need the Dispatcher to do that.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
        if (_openedWindow.Opacity == 1)
                animationStop();
            else
                _openedWindow.Opacity += .1;
}));
```

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is not working. It gives "Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.."

Comment: Try `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`

Comment: I could answer this, but you almost provider the complete solution. If you replace _Dispatcher.BeginInvoke_ with **_openedWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke**, you will call the right dispatcher. He has a problem between the Class `Dispatcher` and the property of the Window `Dispatcher`

Comment: @Magnus Grindal Bakken: this will go wrong if he's on another thread.